# Self Signed Cert error for all users to site

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I know next to nothing about certs or site security. I'm a communications professional. I am however entrusted with fixing our company website.

[www.cjfe.org](http://www.cjfe.org)

Visiting the website kicks up an untrusted certificate error for new arrivals. this wouldn't be a problem if our primary user base did not have a specific focus on civil liberties and privacy.

Now, getting HTTPS set up for our entire site is not an option. We do not have shell access, can't install Lets Encrypt and the hosting service we use (also our CRM provider) only offers encryption for $1000/month as part of their enterprise package, which we're not.

We're not concerned about offering encryption across our whole site. We are however concerned about the errors being kicked back to our users about our site. We think it's happening for any user who is running EFF's HTTPS Everywhere, which is 90% of our audience.

This has a huge impact on our traffic and I know nothing about how to resolve this. Can somebody please help diagnose this and suggest a workaround which will restore normal functionality to our site?

THANKS!

Comment: "offers encryption for $1000/month"  interesting provider you got there. My Recommendation: Switch to a better one.

Comment: Apart from that: I would expect _every_ client to get a serious warning if you are using self signed certificates. Simply because that makes sense. If you want to really offer the kind of security you try to show to your users, then you have to implement that. Everything else would be fraud! So that means you have to use a proper certificate chain _per definition_ of your question. And if your current situation does not allow that, then you either have to drop ssl encryption or you have to change the situation.

Comment: 'drop ssl encryption' what do you mean? We don't have shell access, we don't offer ssl encryption currently AFAIK. Where would I have the option to remove it?

Comment: for the record our hosting provider is www.nationbuilder.com which is far from disreputable. They're used by the largest political parties and nonprofits in the world. We just don't have the budget to give us access to their enterprise level service.

Comment: The cert is **not selfsigned**. Your site is on Akamai: `www.cjfe.org` -> `nameproxy1.nationbuilder.com` -> `www.nationbuilder.com.mdc.edgesuite.net ` and edgesuite is Akamai, and it serves a perfectly **valid cert _for Akamai_ just not for your domain**. Akamai apparently charges more for 'custom' SSL domainnames, although I couldn't find if it's as much as nationbuilder would charge you; I'd guess probably. not.